# Inserting an array using ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a web service which returns the profile of the user upon successful authentication. The profile is in JSON and looks like this:

```
{
  "first_name" : "John",
  "last_name" : "Doe",
  "interests: : ["Science","Sports"]
}
```

How can I persist this in the database using a `ContentProvider`?

`ContentValues` do not have any provision for handling multi-valued attribute. My current implementation looks like this:

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values){
    switch(matcher.match(uri)){
        case NEW_PROFILE:
        break;
        default:
        return null;
    }
    ProfileDatabaseHelper helper = new ProfileDatabaseHelper();
    // delete the existing profile first
    helper.deleteUserProfile();
    // then add a new profile
    long id = helper.addUserProfile( values );
    if( id > -1 ){
        Uri insertedId = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI,id);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertedId,null);
        return insertedId;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `table` to store interests with columns `_id` and `interest` 
Then create another table to store mapping of profile with interests with columns `_id` , `profile_id` and `interest_id`

Create `ContentUri` for each table and insert accordingly.

Comment: I was reading a little more into how I could insert arrays with my content provider. I think `applyBatch()` is the way to go. However, would my `ContentProvider` need to override `applyBatch()` or would the default implementation do just fine ?

Comment: the default implementation of `applyBatch()` should do fine. You just need to handle all the `ContentUri` correctly in the `insert` method